# Function of set of variables except 2

Tags: functions, notation

I want show a function $f$ depends on $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$ except two, $x_a$ and $x_b$, but I don't know best way to denote it. Is this okay?

$$X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$$
$$f(X\setminus\{x_a,x_b\})$$

or is this better?

$$f\Big((x_l)_{l\neq a,b}\Big)$$

Comment: The second one is ok.

Comment: Either is fine as long as you explain yourself clearly. Neither will be widely understood without an explanation.

Comment: There's a crucial difference here: is the arity of $f$ $n$ or $n-2$? One means that it takes $n$ variables but only depends on $n-2$, and the other means that it simply takes and depends on $n-2$ variables.

Comment: @orlp $n-1$ if $a = b$ is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I once saw this notation, I think it was in a book by Spivak, but I'm not sure

$$f(x_1, \ldots, \check{x}_a,\ldots,\check{x}_b,\ldots,x_n)$$